# wait for finish buffer data with rxjs observable

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, buffer

I am getting redis cache data and want to return data after finish but here data returned chunks so this leads to incomplete data

```
const checkDetailCache = (key: string): Observable<any> => {

    const getCache = bindNodeCallback(storageClient.get.bind(storageClient)) as (key: string) => Observable<any>;

    return (getCache(key).pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(
            (value) => iif(
                () => value === null,
                of(null),
                of(value).pipe(
                    map((result: Buffer) => {
                        // return data after finish 
                        return result.toString();
                    }),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

is there any way to finish all buffer data then only process with rxjs operators or did i make any mistake in my code

Comment: So `getCache` emits a stream of values that completes at some point. And you want to return a combined value out of your observable? Can you recreate in a minimal demo - not necessarily using a real redis cache.

Comment: i think we can use toArray operator which collects all data from stream

Comment: You can, although you have no need in your example as you're using `first`. I don't really know what's going on in your code, so can't really comment much more until I see a working demo.

Comment: And your whole `switchMap` could be replaced by a simple `map`

Comment: In this example, at least...

Comment: yes, i have adjusted code as per your suggestion, what i am doing here, i should check cache, if exist do http request else get value from cache and return data `checkDetailCache(key).pipe( map((val) => { if (val === null) { // do some http stuff and return data as observable } else { return val // return cache data } }) )`

Comment: somehow not succeed with toArray getting data like this if i make console, starting with  [

Comment: Can you show in a demo?